# The number of very small eigenvalues of a adjacency matirx

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

When I calculate the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of a graph, which has 34 nodes and 78 edges, I found that there are many eigenvalues close to zero, like, $3.52059077e-16$.

The question is that is there any approach I can use to get the number of these very small eigenvalues of an adjacency matrix?

Comment: Were these eigenvalues calculated with a computer? because computers make floating point errors, so might they actually be $0$? If that is the case, the number of non-zero eigenvalues of a matrix is the rank.

Comment: Thx. You are right! I just calculated the rank of the adjacency matrix. And it turns out that the rank is exactly the same as the number of non-zero eigenvaluses. These very small eigenvalues I think actually are 0. Apart from that, actually, what I want to know more is how can I get the rank of a adjacency matrix when x edges being added into the graph. That is, when I add 2x "1" entries into the adjacency matrix, and the location of these 2x "1" entries is not fixed, how can I get the rank of the perturbed adjacency matrix. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @Henry: That's a new, different question that shouldn't be discussed at length in the comments. One of you should post the above answer to this question as an answer so you can accept it and the question doesn't remain unanswered; you can ask the new question in a new post.

Comment: @joriki: Thank you for reminding.